# Finding the index of a string that contains a substring recursively

Tags: haskell, recursion

Im trying to find the index of a string in the context of a list that contains a certain substring, with no avail. Im unsure how one may pass the entirety of the untouched array as an argument to another function in a recursive function. Here is my approach:

```
find' :: [String] -> Maybe Int
find' [] = error "List is empty"
find' [x] = return maybe 0
find' (x:xs)
    | "HU" `isInfixOf` x = return elemIndex x (x:xs)
    | otherwise = checkTail
    where checkTail = find' xs
```

The error is namely:

```
 * Couldn't match type `[[String]] -> Maybe Int' with `Maybe Int'
  Expected type: String -> [String] -> Maybe Int
    Actual type: String -> [String] -> [[String]] -> Maybe Int
* The function `return' is applied to three arguments,
  but its type `([String] -> [[String]] -> Maybe Int)
                -> String -> [String] -> [[String]] -> Maybe Int'
  has only four
  In the expression: return elemIndex x (x : xs)
  In an equation for find':
      find' (x : xs)
        | "HU" `isInfixOf` x = return elemIndex x (x : xs)
        | otherwise = checkTail
        where
            checkTail = find' xs

   | "HU" `isInfixOf` x = return elemIndex x (x:xs)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I dont really understand the error and why it doesnt match, because in both cases im returning a maybe int. However as I've mentioned im not sure if (x:xs) actually means the entire list for the argument.
Just to clarify, im trying to find the index of the string from a list of strings.

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what you're trying to do with this - in particular what you mean by `return` and `maybe`. They are both standard functions in Haskell, but I strongly suspect neither does what you think it does. (In particular by `return maybe 0` I *think* you just mean `Just 0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `maybe` is a function by itself; what it does isn't relevant to the question. Suffice to say, `return 0` does what you want: it returns `Just 0` from the function:

```
find' :: [String] -> Maybe Int
find' [] = Nothing
find' [x] = return 0 -- equivalent to find' [x] = Just 0
```

(Note the use of `Nothing`; if you are going to raise an error, there's no reason to use `Maybe Int` instead of `Int` as the return type. Also, there's no reason to use `return` over `Just`, since you aren't trying to support an arbitrary monad here.)

Further, `elemIndex` *already* returns a value of type `Maybe Int`; you don't need to use the `return` function, which wraps the value in another layer, producing a `Maybe (Maybe Int)` value, which is not what you want.

```
find' (x:xs)
    | "HU" `isInfixOf` x = elemIndex x (x:xs)
    | otherwise = find' xs
```

One last problem: if `"HU"` isn't present in the first element of the list, you are correct to simply call `find'` on the tail of the list. However, you need to add 1 to that return value to compensate for passing a shorter argument. (This also means you don't need `elemIndex`, since you always find `"HU"` in the head of the *current* list.)

```
find' (x:xs)
    | "HU" `inInfixOf` x = Just 0
    | otherwise = fmap (1+) (find' xs)
```

You need to use `fmap`; `find'` returns a `Maybe Int`, not an `Int`, so `1 + find' xs` by itself won't work.

This also means you can drop the special case for `[x]`, since it follows from finding the search string in the head of the list. The entire function is just

```
find' :: [String] -> Maybe Int
find' [] = Nothing
find' (x:xs)
    | "HU" `isInfixOf` x = Just 0
    | otherwise = fmap (1+) (find' xs)
```

---

One way that works with the entire list is to search the entire list at once, then find the (first) occurrence of True in the resulting list of booleans.

```
find'' :: [String] -> Maybe Int
find'' xs = elemIndex True (map ("HU" `inInfixOf`) xs)
-- or find'' = elemIndex True . map ("HU" `inInfixOf`)
-- or find'' = findIndex ("HU" `inInfixOf`)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however the question wasnt to find the index of the substring within the string, but to find the index of the string item IF the substring is present in that list element. by taking away the unneccessary returns and using Just 0 in the first valid case, it now compiles properly, but doesnt actually find the suitable String within a list. this is why im trying to use the entire list regardless of the state of recursion with the elemIndex function, because I want to know the index of the string in context of the entire list. but Im still clueless about that part.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I conflated `[String]` to `String` in my mind.

Comment: Could you advise how I might want to change the recursive part for this? Regardless of what list I try the answer is either Just 0 or Nothing, even if 'HU' is really present at index 6. Really infuriating because in my head it makes perfect sense in this stage

Comment: I think my solution seems to be OK at this point, but I cant find anything about how I can use the entire list as an argument to elemIndex (or to other functions for that matter)

Comment: See my update; you don't need `elemIndex` at all, because the only place you look (or find) the string `"HU"` is in the head of the list. By the time you call `inFixOf`, there is no "whole" list to look in; you only have the list received by the current call. That said, you can also contrive a definition that *does* use `elemIndex`.

Comment: Thank you! Last question, what is the difference between ' and '' after the function name?

Comment: Just the obvious one, namely, that they are two different strings; I just wanted to give that version a new name.